# Recognising backslash in awk field separator

Tags: awk

Input is

```
AZE D11/879\x0Dabc\x0D\x0A\x1E!DEF F11/999
```

awk script sets field separator to "\x0D" (I have tried with and without escaping the backslash.

awk script is

```
BEGIN {FS="\\x0D"}
   {print NF}
```

It should output 3 because there are 2 occurrences of the field separator but it outputs 1 which indicates it is not being recognized.

Comment: Well, the rule of thumb is to keep adding  "\"s until it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to provide a regexp in awk - a static regexp (aka regexp literal) written as `/regexp/` and a dynamic regexp (aka computed regexp) written as `"regexp"` and used in a regexp context. A field separator is just a regexp with some additional behavior so lets just consider regexps in general to explain what's going on in your example.

The `split()` function takes a field separator (a regexp for our purposes) as it's third argument so it provides a good test bed:

Using a static regexp:

```
$ awk '{print split($0,a,/\x0D/)}' file
1
```

The `\` above is escaping the `x`, it's not a literal `\`. For that you need to escape the `\` itself:

```
$ awk '{print split($0,a,/\\x0D/)}' file
3
```

What if we used a dynamic regexp instead of the above static regexp?

```
$ awk '{print split($0,a,"\x0D")}' file
1
$ awk '{print split($0,a,"\\x0D")}' file
1
$ awk '{print split($0,a,"\\\x0D")}' file
' is not a known regexp operator FNR=1) warning: regexp escape sequence `\
1
$ awk '{print split($0,a,"\\\\x0D")}' file
3
```

The behavior above is because awk first parses the string to convert it into a regexp (using up one layer of escape chars) and then parses it a second time when **using** it as a regexp (using up a second layer of escape chars).

Unfortunately when you specify a `FS` there is no option to specify it as a literal regexp, it's **always** specified using a string and thus is a dynamic regexp and so needs an extra layer of escaping:

```
$ awk -v FS='\x0D' '{print NF}' file
1
$ awk -v FS='\\x0D' '{print NF}' file
1
$ awk -v FS='\\\x0D' '{print NF}' file
' is not a known regexp operatorence `\
1
$ awk -v FS='\\\\x0D' '{print NF}' file
3
```

Now - what if you were using the wrong type of quotes in the shell part of the script, i.e. `"` instead of `'`? Then you introduce even more pain because now you're inviting the shell to **also** parse the string even before awk gets to see and parse it twice:

```
$ awk -v FS="\\\\x0D" '{print NF}' file
1
$ awk -v FS="\\\\\x0D" '{print NF}' file
' is not a known regexp operatorence `\
1
$ awk -v FS="\\\\\\x0D" '{print NF}' file
' is not a known regexp operatorence `\
1
$ awk -v FS="\\\\\\\x0D" '{print NF}' file
3
```

That's different from the case where the double quotes are using inside awk because that's all wrapped inside single quotes and so protected from the shell already:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\\\x0D"} {print NF}' file
3
```

So - in the shell always use the most restrictive quotes (`'` over `"` over none) unless you have a very specific reason not to, and when using regexps or field separators always use literal `/.../` rather than dynamic `"..."`, again unless you have a very specific reason not to.

The odd, truncated looking error message above are because of the `\r`s the tool is trying to print due to the escape sequence we're providing, they're really all `warning: regexp escape sequence '\^M' is not a known regexp operator`

Answer (score 1):

You need two backslashes for a literal backslash since `\` is an escape character:

```
$ echo 'AZE D11/879\x0Dabc\x0D\x0A\x1E!DEF F11/999' |
    awk 'BEGIN{ FS="\\\\x0D" } { print NF }'
3
```